# An if statement using 'UnityEngine.Random.Range()' only works with very high maximum values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*-Bear in mind I'm fairly inexperienced to Unity and C#-*

The script that the problem takes place in is a class to hold all of the important subroutines and functions for animal AI. This particular section of the C# script causes the animals to pathfind to a random location for a random amount of time before stopping (this is the only approach to a random movement AI I could think of as it makes use of the pathfinding code I had already written). The way it works is that it instantiates an empty GameObject in a random x,z position 50 units above the ground, and sets the target position to this GameObject's position, before calling the pathfinding script to navigate to the random location.
The following script is found in the FixedUpdate method (FixedUpdate as opposed to Update so it runs slightly less frequently), and ensures the random movement does not occur every frame.

```
int randNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 100000);
if (randNum <= 10)
{
    StartCoroutine(DelayForRandomMovement());
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that the maximum value in the Random.Range call, `randNum`, *has* to be 100000, or a single, important line in the DelayForRandomMovement() coroutine will not run as expected. This coroutine is as follows:

```
IEnumerator DelayForRandomMovement()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(UnityEngine.Random.Range(1f, 6f)); //wait 1-6 seconds
    stop = false;

    if (stop == false)
    {
        GameObject randomPosObj = Instantiate(randomMovementPrefab);
        randomPosObj.transform.position = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-240, 240), 50, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-240, 240)); //instantiate empty prefab in random x and z pos within range of island size
        target = randomPosObj.transform; //target = the instantiated prefab

        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rabbit>().LocateFood();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(UnityEngine.Random.Range(3f, 6f)); //wait 3-6 seconds
        Destroy(randomPosObj);
    }
}
```

The line of code that doesn't execute properly is `this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rabbit>().LocateFood()`, and I have no idea why. This line calls the LocateFood() subroutine (in this case being used to pathfind to a position, not food), from the Rabbit class (a child class of the current class/script). The LocateFood() sub uses various other scripts for calculations, so I will include its contents at the very bottom of this post.

`this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rabbit>().LocateFood()` still executes when `randNum` is less than 100000, but the problem is that the animals simply do not pathfind. I know this because a Debug.Log() command in the LocateFood() sub still gets executed when it should. However, when the max value *is* set to 100000, the animals do pathfind as expected and it works flawlessly. The only problem there is that it happens incredibly infrequently, resulting in a lot of unmoving rabbits.

I can't recite exactly what I have done to try and fix it, but I've fiddled with this part of the code over and over and nothing has seemed to work so I've had to revert to the state you see now. Would anyone know of any ways this can be rewritten, or give any tips for why this could be happening? Thanks for any help.

---

**EDIT:**
Here are the contents of `LocateFood()`:

```
public override void LocateFood()
{
    PathRequestManager.RequestPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathFound);
}
```

I know that the `RequestPath()` method gets called fine because text got output into the console as expected. The nodes get calculated and their gizmos get shown in Unity scene view. So, I will only show the contents of the callback subroutine, `OnPathFound()`:

```
public void OnPathFound(Vector3[] waypoints, bool pathSuccessful)
{
    Debug.Log("Path found");
    if (pathSuccessful)
    {
        path = new Path(waypoints, transform.position, turnDst, stoppingDst); ;
        StopCoroutine("FollowPath");
        StartCoroutine("FollowPath");
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
I will paste in the current code to show how things are working now:

`Update():`

```
// checks every frame to see if the timer has reached zero
if (timer <= 0)
{
    if (!moving)
    {
        // if animal is not moving AND the timer has reached zero, determine whether movement happens based off chance
        int randNum = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10000);
        if (randNum <= chance)
        {
            RandomMovement();
        }
    }
    else //if animal is currently moving and timer reached zero
    {
        StopRandomMovement();
    }
    timer = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minInterval, maxInterval); // reset the interval timer
}
else
{
    // otherwise, if the timer is greater than zero, reduce the timer by Time.deltaTime (the time in seconds since the last frame)
    timer -= Time.deltaTime; // timer counts down
}
```

`RandomMovement():`

```
Debug.Log("starting wander");
target = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-boundSize, boundSize), height, UnityEngine.Random.Range(-boundSize, boundSize));
rabbit.LocateFood();

moving = true;
```

`StopRandomMovement():`

```
Debug.Log("stopping wander");
StopCoroutine("FollowPath");

moving = false;
```

The problem that I am now facing is that the rabbit doesn't pathfind.
However, the code seems to execute as expected: the `moving` boolean value gets set to true every so often, before being set to false a few seconds later; the correct `Debug.Log()` messages also show in the console at the correct moments; and the `target` Vector3 variable also displays an appropriate random location in the inspector as should happen. *This also suggests that methods running several times at once is no longer the problem.*

So, the new `Update()` code appears to be working as expected, but the rabbit just doesn't begin to pathfind, despite the pathfinding code still running as demonstrated by the "Path requested" console output (which executes within one of the first few methods for the pathfinding algorithm). I will litter some more `Debug.Log()`s throughout the various pathfinding methods/functions to hopefully show me where the problem lies.

What's weird, though, is that the pathfinding executes perfectly if I run it once by itself on a button press, and it did work fine at one point when testing this updated code, as I mentioned in my last comment. I haven't made any changes whatsoever to any of the pathfinding code since I created this post, so I find it odd that it only works sometimes.

Comment: `if (randNum <= 10)` There is like a 1 in 10,000 chance this will be true. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @001 I would prefer the odds to be far higher but the 1 in a 10,000 chance is the only way to get my code to work atm

Comment: Can you share the `LocateFood()` method? Without seeing what's inside that, we can't say why what's inside isn't happening.

Comment: I've added the `LocateFood()` method at the bottom of the post but I'm not sure how much help it would be. Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, `FixedUpdate()` is often called more frequently than `Update()` as it is essentially the physics update loop which, as it states in the name, happens at a fixed time interval unlike `Update()` which runs as frequently as there are frames shown.

By default Unity tries to run the fixed update method at about 50 times a second, which means in a game running at 25fps you will have around 2 physics updates in the time one frame has passed.

In fact, this may be the root of your issue. If you are starting coroutines in the fixed update, or the update for that matter, that means you will be starting a whole bunch of coroutines every frame. Starting a new coroutine does not stop any previous ones from running!
So it is likely you have a bunch of coroutines running at once which are running conflicting logic, like setting a new target every split second.

You didn't really make it clear exactly **how** the "line of code that doesn't execute properly". Is it not setting the target? Is it setting it but not moving the animal towards it?

Also, calling `this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rabbit>().LocateFood();` makes little sense if `Rabbit` is a child/extended class of this one.
You should either:

- Override this coroutine in the `Rabbit` class to do the logic specific to the rabbit.
  OR
- Move this logic to the `Rabbit` class if it is not applicable to all animals.
  OR
- If you really need it here, rather just check if this object is a rabbit `if (this is Rabbit)` or `if (this.GetType() == typeof(Rabbit))`.

For the sake of debugging this problem, maybe swap out the code that only starts the coroutine with a 1 in 10,000 chance for code that runs it when you press a button or something more deterministic/certain.

Lastly, kinda unrelated but, you set `stop = false` then on the very next line check `if (stop == false)`. This is completely redundant as stop will alway be false because you've just set it to that the line before.

EDIT: Here's a proposed system that really simplifies things and mitigates the risk of compounding coroutines, by removing them. Let me also mention that coroutines have largely been replaced with the async/await patterns.

```
// Having this means you don't have to type UnityEngine.Random.Range(...) everywhere, just Random.Range(...).
using UnityEngine;

public class Animal
{
    // I've created variables for some of the hardcoded values you used.
    // You will need to make these protected or public if you want to access them in your extended classes like the Rabbit class.
    [SerializeField]
    private float chance = 0.0001f; 
    [SerializeField]
    private float minInterval = 1;
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxInterval = 6;
    private float timer;

    [SerializeField]
    private float boundSize = 240f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float height = 50f;

    void Update()
    {
        // Checks every frame to see if the timer has reached zero.
        if (tickTimer <= 0)
        {
            // If it has, determine the chance of the movement happening.
            // I've normalized the value here but, since the chance variable is set to 0.0001 the chance is still the same as before, 1 in 10,000.
            float randNum = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
            if (randNum <= chance)
            {
                RandomMovement()
            }
            // Whether the movement happened or not, reset the interval timer.
            timer = Random.Range(minInterval, maxInterval);

            // This is where you could cancel previous movement if you wanted to.
        }
        else
        {
            // Else if the timer is greater than zero, just reduce the timer by Time.deltaTime (the time, in seconds, since the last frame).
            // If it has been 1 second since the last frame (which would be horrible of course) then this will reduce the timer by that amount.
            // So this will count down in seconds.
            // Remember this is not the same for FixedUpdate() as that has a fixed time interval. We use Time.fixedDeltaTime to get that value.
            timer -= Time.deltaTime();
        }
    }

    void RandomMovement()
    {
        // You previously created a new GameObject every time you called this which is bad practice as this literally creates a new object in RAM each time.
        // Also, you only use the position value of the transform which is already Vector3 so you can skip that whole instantiation process you had.
        // You will need to change 'target' to a Vector3 of course.
        target = new Vector3(Random.Range(-boundSize, boundSize), height, Random.Range(-boundSize, boundSize));
    }
}
```

If you wanted the interval to be set as the animal is activated then you can put set it in Start(), Awake(), or OnEnable(). OnEnable() is probably best as this is called whenever the object is activated, not just at the start of the game.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I've tidied up the code a bit, following your guidance. I have swapped `FixedUpdate()` for `Update()` and moved the `DelayForRandomMovement()` logic into an override in the `Rabbit` class.
As for the bug, I have taken the steps you stated to help with debugging, and it now works as intended when I run it a single time with a button press. However, it still doesn't work if I try calling it in the weird `Update()` method logic I wrote. Do you know of another way to make a function run rarely? The `Random.Range(1, 10000)` method seems to be inherently a bad idea.

Comment: @RyanGray I think you need another condition to start for DelayForRandomMovement() coroutine. For example, you can check if rabbit reached to its destination, or stopped moving, if it didn't reach than don't start a new coroutine.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of some help. I still think your issue is the compounding coroutines.

You could create a simple boolean value like `isBusy` (or something like that) which will be checked if it is not true, then set to true when the coroutine is run, then set back to false when it is done.
Otherwise, what I think would be much better is to rather start this coroutine only when the previous act of following is completed instead of every frame.
Though I would personally drop the coroutines altogether and swap it for a cooldown/tick. I'll have to update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. After implementing your code, it appeared to work, but only without the `StopCoroutine("FollowPath");` line, meaning the animals kept navigating their path until they reached the target location. So, I added to the code to ensure the rabbits stop moving only if they are currently moving each time the timer reaches 0. This way, it doesn't stop the pathfinding immediately after beginning it. However, I have come across a problem stopping the rabbit from pathfinding, so I will update my original post to explain it.

Comment: Oh my god I fixed the problem. It now works as intended with no problems. Maybe I implemented it wrong, but setting the interval values in `Awake()`, `Start()`, or `OnEnable()`, didn't seem to delay the animal's ability to start pathfinding. Instead, I made a new bool variable and set it to true 3 seconds after `Start()` gets run. Then I made it so the pathfinding code in the `Update()` method can only run if this variable is true. So, the animals no longer try to pathfind along a grid that doesn't yet exist, because of this delay. It's a stupid bug that took too long to fix, but it works now!

Comment: I should also thank you again for your help, this is my first time using stack overflow and you listened carefully and gave thoroughly explained and useful advice. Your code works so much better than my original code and doesn't allow for multiple, clashing instances of the same method to run at once. Again, thank you!! :))

Comment: Hey @nicko you are more than welcome. I genuinely enjoy solving problems and helping others do so too. I'm glad I could help in this case. Keep up the coding and, most importantly, have fun!